# Handling Internationalization using Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, localization, internationalization

we are working on a travelling portal which is going to be in place for all major locales and currently using Struts2+Spring+Hibernate as core platforms.
for handling localization for static contents like labels and other things we can easily achieve with the build in support of Struts2 using resource bundles.
but when it comes for the dynamic contents like we have a destination and it is going to have a lot of dynamic contents like its descriptions,places of interests etc.
since this data can be quite large and we can not solve this problem with resource bundle so there needs some way to store this data in the database and fetch the respected coronets based on the locale information.

My question is how best we can do this with hibernate? currently we have only one table for destination which is containing major information about the destination and all other information about related to Destination is in there respective tables,so its not seems good idea to create columns in each table for each locale since we in advance do not know how many more locales can be added in future so idea is to come up with a generic or a more flexible solution.

Any suggestion/help in this regard will be much appreciated

**edit1**
After doing some analysis all i came to conclusion that we can achieve the above objective using Hibernate user type,My question is have any one tried this way..or do any one have achieved the goal by some other way..any suggestion in this case will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this answer for internationalization with Hibernate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7612810/412446