# Hibernate mapping for multilanguage support

Tags: hibernate, multilingual

I have a Category class which has id, name, description attributes.

I want that user can enter multilingual **name and description** and save them.

What should be the structure of the class and the hibernate mapping?

This is my code with annotations. But I couldn't insert anything to database:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "category")
public class Category {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}
private Integer id;
private Map<String, TranslatedString> name;
private Map<String, TranslatedString> description;



@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name = "translated_string")
@MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "langCode")
public Map<String, TranslatedString> getName() {
    return this.name;
}

public void setName(Map<String, TranslatedString> name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name = "translated_string")
@MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "langCode")
public Map<String, TranslatedString> getDescription() {
    return this.description;
}

public void setDescription(Map<String, TranslatedString> description) {
    this.description = description;
}



}


@Embeddable
public class TranslatedString {

public Integer getTid() {
    return tid;
}

public void setTid(Integer tid) {
    this.tid = tid;
}

private Integer tid;



private String langCode;

@Column(name = "langCode")
public String getLangCode() {
    return langCode;
}

public void setLangCode(String langCode) {
    this.langCode = langCode;
}

private String text;

@Column(name = "text")
public String getText() {
    return text;
}

public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}

}
```

I have two tables:
translated_string : tid, text, langCode
category: id, name_id, description_id

I am getting this info message:
Hibernate: insert into category values ( )
when I want to save the category by hibernateTemplate.

And when I want to find a category by id, it executes

```
select 

name0_.Category_id as Category1_0_0_, 
name0_.langCode as langCode0_, 
name0_.text as text0_, 
name0_.tid as tid0_, 
name0_.name_KEY as name5_0_ 

from translated_string name0_ 

where name0_.Category_id=?
```

Since my translated_string table doesn't have Category_id or name_KEY fields, i think I have a problem with the mapping.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Good question! my guess is that you'll need to make one index for each language (unless you want to mix them), but no idea about the mapping, maybe using request_locale in the mapping file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Category {
    public int Id;
    public Map<Language, String> names;
    public Map<Language, String> descriptions;

    public String getCurrentName()
    {
        // get current Language from somewhere
        return names.GetValue(currentLanguage);
    }
}
```

and the mapping

```
<map name="names" table="names">
  <key column="categoryid" />
  <index column="language_id" />
  <element column="value"/>
</map>

<map name="descriptions" table="descriptions">
  <key column="categoryid" />
  <index column="language_id" />
  <element column="value" length="whatever"/>
</map>
```

my java is a bit rusty, feel free to correct syntax

Update: annotations for simple string maps, which should suffice

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name="TranslatedStrings", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="names_category_id"))
@Column(name="value")
public Map<String, String> getNames()

@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name="TranslatedStrings", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="descriptions_category_id"))
@Column(name="value")
public Map<String, String> getDescriptions()


public String getCurrentName()
{
    // get current Language from somewhere
    return names.GetValue(currentLanguage.getCode());
}
```

Comment: I don't have 2 tables, I just have TranslatedStrings table.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6350415/internationalization-with-hibernate is the same topic. But I couldn't insert anyting. It is saying: Hibernate: insert into category values ( )
then gives error

Comment: Hibernate: insert into category values ( ) means there is no data to insert. And because my columns are NOT NULL, it gives an error.

Comment: looks like a different problem. does it insert when you comment out the maps?

Comment: I got this error when I wanted to insert without maps: Could not execute JDBC batch update; SQL [insert into translated_string (Category_id, description_KEY, langCode, text, tid) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)];

Comment: how yould you possibly get an insert to translated strings when you save without maps???

Comment: Sorry, I removed all maps. Just I am inserting emty category: Hibernate: insert into category values ( )
And I can see the row in the DB.